# Google sheets script Auto-run a script and add function in the menu bar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I use a script that allows me to delete the empty rows in the middle of my table and also constantly adds rows at the bottom so that I can keep filling it.
Everything works perfectly.
I just want the script to run automatically if I delete or add a value in the "C" column. And also, if possible, add a function in my menu bar with onOpen(e) in case the script doesn't execute and I have to run it manually.
This is my Sheets:

[My Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CPcMx3Dhbqi-zO4D3jYNxO-PGjyW3iTfRo5gRmEB9p4/edit#gid=0)

This is the script:

```
function removeEmpty() {
  const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Suivi Clients');
  const empty_rows = [];
  const lastRow = sh.getLastRow()
  const data = sh.getRange("C6:G" + lastRow).getValues();
  for (var i in data) if (data[i].join('') == '') empty_rows.push(+i + 6);
  empty_rows.reverse().forEach(x => sh.deleteRow(x));
  sh.insertRowsAfter(lastRow - empty_rows.length, 5)

  var rng = sh.getRange('A6:Z6')
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('A' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':Z' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false);

  // H-I-J-K-L
  var rng = sh.getRange('H' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':L' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('H' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':L' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  // O
  var rng = sh.getRange('O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':O' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  // Q-R-S-T-U
  var rng = sh.getRange('Q' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':U' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('Q' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':U' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);
  // X-Y 
  var rng = sh.getRange('X' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length) + ':Y' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length))
  rng.copyTo(sh.getRange('X' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 1) + ':Y' + (lastRow - empty_rows.length + 5)), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA, false);

}
```

Comment: what is the question? You don't know how to detect which column was edited inside an onEdit(e) script? it is easy, get it from e.range.getColumn()

Comment: No, just want to add onOpen(e) to this script and also onEdit(e) if possible.

Comment: The difficulty is to detect also the event of multicells deleting at the same time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sh.getName() != 'Suivi Clients') return;
  var editRange = { 
    top: 6, 
    left: 3, 
    right: 7 
  };
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;
  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;
  removeEmpty()
}
```

and

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' remove empty lines', 'removeEmpty')
    .addToUi();
  removeEmpty()
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mike, All is working nice!

Answer (score 0):

I think your goal is as follows:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const {range} = e
  /* Ensure that the edit occurs in the column 3 === C */
  if(range.getColumn() === 3 && range.getLastColumn() === 3){
    removeEmpty()
  }
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu().addItem('Remove Empty', 'removeEmpty').addToUi()
}
```